# definition of an adele of a function field

Tags: algebraic-geometry, divisors-algebraic-geometry, function-fields

From the book "Algebraic function fields and codes" of Stichtnoth, we have the definition that i can't seem to understand :

[image]

where $\mathbb{P}_F$ is the set of places of the function field $F/K$. $\mathcal{O}_P$ is the valuation ring of the place $P$.

How do we choose $\alpha_P$ the image of a place $P$??

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, "How do we choose $\alpha_P$."  Who said anything about choosing?  Please clarify.

Comment: The question is unclear. What exactly are you asking? "For almost all" here means "for all but finitely many places".

Comment: Its a map, to each place we associate an element in F, how do we define the image??

Comment: If the map is already given to you, then you don't define the image.  It's determined by the map...

Comment: aah right , i get it now . thank youuu !!!!!